# How to make an element ~20 em wide

Tags: css, susy-compass

I have a Susy grid with 16 columns. I would like to set the width of a certain element to the minimum number of columns that can contain 30 (r)ems of text.

The effect I want to achieve is that, during resizes, the width of that element is more or less fixed (but aligned with the grid) while the rest of the elements in the page shrink or expand following the resizing of the columns.

How can I set a width to "the (minimum) amount of columns needed to accommodate X (r)ems"?

Comment: You'll have to get creative on this one. It sounds fun, but I'm not sure I have the time for it at the moment. Basically, you want to calculate the actual width of a column at different sizes (taking your breakpoints into account), and change the column-span when it gets too large or small. The math should be fairly straight forward, but the implementation depends a lot on your markup.

Comment: Or, of course, you could eye-ball it and get pretty close.